# Changing Coordinate Frames with Affine Transformations

Tags: computational-geometry, geometry, vector-graphics, linear-algebra

[image]

Stuck with this questions could I get some help.

where uA and vA are two orthonormal vectors indicating the two axes, and oA is the origin.  Suppose that all  three  frames  of  reference  shown  in  Figure  3  are  orthonormal,  and  suppose  that A and B are  related through  the  affine  transformation N,  and A and C are  related  through  the  affine  transformation M.   In particular,B=AN,and C=AM.Derive an expression of M using only the symbolsθ,d, andφ(in Figure 3) (i.e., matrix M is the function of θ,d, andφ ).

Comment: Looks like a homework question. What have you tried?

Comment: I was tried using affine transformations but my got stuck when dealing with abstracting the transformation from A to B with regards to d and phi and theta. I am also a little confused with how to deal with the transformation matrix being on the right side of the coordinate frame matrix. I am stuck and not sure where to start with this question.

Comment: Show us your work.